# How to check all strings before doing the next step

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach, logic, string-comparison

I want to perform string-comparison. I use a foreach loop, but I want to do `move-item` after all strings have been compared.

My concept is   " If all of strings not match, do `move-item`. "

How can I do that?

here is my present code but it is  " if match,do `move-item`

```
$Myfile=dir *my file name*
$directory=dir D:\example    (there are many directory)

foreach($dir in $directory){
 if($dir match $Myfile.basename ){
   move-item $Myfile.fullname -destination D:\example
 }
}
```

I want to do  `move-item` after string comparison to ensure that `my file name` doesn't exist `$directory`
here is what I want to achieve

```
if( ("all of the directory Name") -notmatch $myfile.basename ){
  move-item XXX to XXX
}
```

if I use -notmatch , it will do move-item at the first time loop. So I need to do  `move-item` after checking them all...

Comment: can you please provide us at least the foreach loop of your code?

Comment: @Nicicalu update my code

Comment: Is the above code not working?

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh hi,it is working.But I wanna a opposite condition

Comment: Then why not use `-notmatch` instead of `-match`

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh if I use `-notmatch` , it will do `move-item` at the first time loop.  So I need to check them all...

Comment: @Dukeyu Thank you for providing us the code. With that information I could provide you with an answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable to true if something matches:

```
$Myfile=dir *my file name*
$directory=dir D:\example    (there are many directory)

$move = $false
foreach($dir in $directory){
    if($dir match $Myfile.basename ){
        $move = $true
    }
}
if ($move){
    move-item $Myfile.fullname -destination D:\example
}
```

Comment: No problem! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can try using notcontains operator to check the file base name appears in the directory files :

```
$myfile = get-childitem "filepath"
$directory = @(get-childitem "D:\Example" | foreach {$_.basename})
if ($directory -notcontains $myfile.basename) {
  move-item xxx to xxx
}
```